# a bug in malloc which used to copy array elements

Tags: c

This code is meant to copy an int array with count elements to a newly applied memory area in the heap.

```
int copy(int *array ,int count){
 int i;
 int *myarray = (int*)malloc(count*sizeof(int));
  if (myarray == NULL)
   return -1;
  for(int i = 0;i<count;i++)
  {
     myarray[i]=array[i];
  }
return count;
```

i think maybe it forgets to use free() after using the malloc()  function to free the memory but this code is meant to copy array element in the memory.so whether i am right ? If no, what is the really bug?

Comment: `malloc` does not call `free` for you. That's **your** responsibility.

Comment: What's the point of the function if it doesn't return the newly allocated array?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `memcpy`?

Comment: Whether it is right depends on the context. If you are on modern OS and not calling `copy()` too many times, the memory used will be freed by the OS after the process exites and it won't be a problem. If you want to use the copied array later, you have to take it out (maybe as return value).

Comment: yeah，i don't know why this function do not return the *myarray,maybe it just wants to copy the elements to  the memory.

Comment: This codes allocates an array, copies some data into that array, then does nothing with the array and forgets all about it. So... what is the code actually supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

This function leaks memory.

`myarray` contains a pointer to allocated memory which contains a copy of the data in `array`.  However, this pointer is not used in any way when the function returns so the pointer to the allocated memory is lost.

The function should return a pointer to this memory so that it can be used.

```
int *copy(int *array ,int count){
  int i;
  int *myarray = malloc(count*sizeof(int));

  if (myarray == NULL)
    return -1;
  for(int i = 0;i<count;i++)
  {
     myarray[i]=array[i];
  }
  return myarray;
}
```

Note that it will be the responsibility of the calling function to `free` the memory when it is done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `copy` function functions allocates memory and then copies the elements of the array to that newly allocated memory. So far so good, but then you simply throw away the pointer to that newly allocated memory.

It's like copying a letter by hand, putting the copy into a safe, closing the safe with the key and then throw the key away. Now the copy of the letter is in the safe, but you can't access it any more.

You probably want something like this:

```
...
int *copy(int *array, int count)  // return a pointer to int, not an int
{
  int *myarray = malloc(count*sizeof(int));  // (int*) cast is not needed
  if (myarray == NULL)
   return NULL;                   // return NULL if malloc fails

  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
     myarray[i] = array[i];
  }

  return myarray;                 // return pointer to newly allocated memory
}

...

int source[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *destination = copy(source, 5);
if (destination == NULL)
{
  // handle error
}

// now destination points the the copy of the array

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  printf("%d\n", destination[i]);
}
...
free(destination);                // free allocated memory when you're done with it
...
```